# Перенос сообщений без пробелов на новую строку php

Tags: php, html, css

Всем привет. Заметил баг на сайте, а точнее в комментариях. Когда пользователь оставляет сообщение без пробелов и длиннее чем размер блока для комментариев, то сообщение выходит за пределы блока и это выглядит безобразно. Сделал для блока css:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Тогда комментарий не выходит за пределы блока, а лишь, как бы, за пределами становится невидимым. Но это так же плохо. Необходимо переносить текст на новую строку, если размер текста больше либо равен блоку отведенному для комментариев.
Как можно реализовать такую проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом Вам поможет не всем известное, прекрасное CSS-свойство [`word-wrap`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap), после его использования Вы почувствуете фантастический прилив сил.

Answer (score 0):

На PHP это можно сделать, используя функцию "WordWrap()":

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
echo $newtext;
```

Где $text-сам текст, 20 - число символов, после которого надо вставить какой-либо тег или символ(в нашем случае - перенос)