# Как сделать автоперенос слов на следующую строку?

Tags: html, css

К примеру в HTML докумете я вывожу текст, но если он слишком длинный то слово может разорваться на две части (к примеру слово "Мышь" может разорваться на "М" и "ышь" и в итоге М останется на первой строке, а "ышь" пойдет на следующее. Так вот - есть ли в CSS такое свойство, которое автоматически переводит на следующую строку не части слов, а сами слова?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> word-wrap:break-word

Comment: Ты не правильно вставляешь код. Зачем нажимать на «010101», а потом еще и на цитату?

Comment: учту) . . .

Comment: Изменяй давай!

Answer (score 2):

Атрибут стиля `word-wrap` применяется нечасто, но в некоторых случаях без него не обойтись. Он позволяет указать места, в которых Web-обозреватель может выполнить разрыв текста:

```
word-wrap: normal|break-word|inherit
```

Здесь доступны два значения.
 `normal` — указывает Web-обозревателю, что он может разрывать текст на строки только по пробелам. Это обычное поведение Web-обозревателя.
 `break-word` — разрешает Web-обозревателю выполнять разрыв текста на строки внутри слов. Это может пригодиться, если текст содержит много очень длинных слов, которые по ширине не помещаются в родительский элемент.
Пример:

```
<style type=text/css">
P { word-wrap: normal; }
</style>
```

Здесь мы разрешили Web-обозревателю выполнять разрыв текста на строки в содержимом тегов <P> (т. е. в абзацах) только между пробелами.
ps Незабудте поставить галочку :)

Comment: Ответили же уже два раза.

Answer (score 1):

[Перенос сообщений без пробелов на новую строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/85960#85964).