# Как сделать разбитие строки без пробелов?

Tags: css

```html
<div style="width:40px">
   <span>ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</span>  
<div>
```

Если строка длиннее 40px, она должна переноситься на следующую строку - как это сделать? Строка без пробелов.

Comment: Что значит «падала ниже»?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перенос сообщений без пробелов на новую строку php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/85960/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует свойство `word-wrap`. Его, кстати, очень легко найти в интернете *(если искать)*. Если вы установите `word-wrap: break-word;`, то слова будут автоматически разбиваться и переноситься на следующую строку, как вы и хотите. Надо учитывать, что данное свойство является черновым и при валидации CSS3 будет давать ошибку.

Ещё можно использовать свойство `overflow-wrap: break-word;`.

> Изначально свойство word-wrap не было стандартом, хотя и было
> реализовано большинством браузеров. Впоследствии оно было
> переименовано в overflow-wrap c алиасом word-wrap.

Делаю вывод, что лучше всего вам подойдёт `overflow-wrap: break-word;`.

[Источник](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap)